# Difference between using callbacks and calling methods

Tags: javascript, function, asynchronous, callback

I'm very new to Javascript programming and was researching ways in dealing with asynchronous functions. I came across really helpful resource which lists this as an example:

```
var fs = require('fs')
var myNumber = undefined

function addOne(callback) {
    fs.readFile('number.txt', function doneReading(err, fileContents) {
        myNumber = parseInt(fileContents)
        myNumber++
        callback()
    })
}

function logMyNumber() {
    console.log(myNumber)
}

addOne(logMyNumber)
```

However could you achieve the same result doing this:

```
var fs = require('fs')
var myNumber = undefined

function addOne() {
    fs.readFile('number.txt', function doneReading(err, fileContents) {
        myNumber = parseInt(fileContents)
        myNumber++
        logMyNumber()
    })
}

function logMyNumber() {
    console.log(myNumber)
}

addOne()
```

And if you can, what would be the purpose/advantage of using callbacks?

For those interested the article came from here: https://github.com/maxogden/art-of-node#callbacks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we use call back it depend on situation in to make things dynamic or make sure that a code of piece run after one is complete.in your current code already describe callbacks

your first example clearly state how we define callbacks.

> In computer programming, a callback is a piece of executable code that is passed as an argument to other code, which is expected to call back (execute) the argument at some convenient time. The invocation may be immediate as in a synchronous callback, or it might happen at later time as in an asynchronous callback

```
var fs = require('fs')
var myNumber = undefined
```

you are using call back here which give you power to run different- different method after reading number.txt successfully

```
function addOne(callback) {
    fs.readFile('number.txt', function doneReading(err, fileContents) {
        myNumber = parseInt(fileContents)
        myNumber++
        callback()
    })
}
```

in  your second example there is no callback you are calling logMyNumber()  directly, what if we need to run another function something like

```
function logMyNumber() {
    console.log(myNumber)
}

function varifynumber() {
    console.log(myNumber)
}

function somthingelse() {
    console.log(myNumber)
}


addOne(logMyNumber)
addOne(somthingelse)
addOne(logMyNumber)
```

and the other best use of callbacks in JavaScript is handle  asynchronous tasks, if you noticed 
inside your function you are using  `fs.readFile('number.txt',callback)` which is a  asynchronous method please have look below example

```
console.log('start');
 fs.readFile('number.txt', function doneReading(err, fileContents) {
          // until the file not read completely this section will not run 
          // this happend because of call back  
        console.log('Reading complete');
        })
console.log('End');

output :
start
End
Reading complete
```

i hope this will help you

Comment: Great explanation! I've spent a good part of the day playing around with callbacks and found them to be extremely helpful to what was very unpredictable code. Good to see the different examples used and why it's not a good idea to call directly - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what you are trying to achieve. In the first example, the function `addOne` has no concept on what the callback parameter does, it just invokes it.

However, in the second case, the `addOne` function knows it will invoke `logMyNumber`, and therefore has a tighter coupling and concept of what exactly is going on.

The first example is often favorable in most cases, e.g. if you are splitting functions across multiple files, and don't want them to be tightly intertwined.

Comment: I see, so with the second example would you still be able to get the readFile function to finish first before calling logMyNumber?

Comment: After calling `fs.readFile`, the program just resumes, and sometime in the future, the second parameter you provided to the function will execute. I have formatted your example a bit to make it clearer.